# Understanding RegExp

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to make a parser in Python and I think RegExp can be of great use to avoid lots of 'if-statements' to check if the input is correct.

I have the following expression

```
for i | if i < 100 | increment i{
    lots of lines of code each ending with;
};
```

1. I want to check if the first `i` starts with a letter(lower or uppercase);
2. Then it can be any number of alphanum;
3. Followed by `|` and `if`. I'm using:
4. then the same as the first `i` (i don't think I can store the first and check if is the same? Can I?)
5. then operator and `|` and any number of digits.
6. then either 4 spaces or 1 tab and ending with a `;`
7. and finally the `};` ending.

I got some of those, but I can't manage to put them together.

Here's what I got, please point out what I'm doing wrong.

I got so far:

```
^for [a-z|A-Z]\w* \| if [a-z|A-Z]\w* [<|>|==|>=|<=] \d+ \| [increment|decrement] [a-z|A-Z]\w*{\n[ {4}|\t].*;\n};$
```

Breakdown:

- `[a-z|A-Z]\w`    start with a letter (either upper and lower case), and that can be followed by any number alphanum.
- `[<|>|==|>=|<=]`    the possible operators.
- `\d+` any number.
- `[increment|decrement]`    this is one is not working, I want to match either of those two words. I tried using `\b` or `^` and `$`.
- `{\n`    the start of the bracket zone.
- `{\n[ {4}|\t].*;`    This is not working either, `{4}` should match 4 spaces and `\t` a tab.
- `\n};$`    The end of the bracket zone.

Please point out any mistake I may encounter with this regex and the goal I'm seaking.

**EDIT:**

I'm getting None when I try to match the @Barmar regex.

Here's the test code:

```
import re
f = "for i | if i < 100 | increment i{\n\tlots of lines of code each ending with;\n};"

print re.findall("^for ([a-zA-z]\w*) \| if \1 (?:<|>|==|>=|<=) \d+ \| (?:increment|decrement) \1{"
               "\n(?: {4}|\t]=).*;\n};$",f)
```

Comment: What language are you using please?

Comment: What will happen if you have a nested if/for?

Comment: Step 1 seems to be missing something. Check if the first `i` starts with what?

Comment: You can use a capture group and back-reference to check if the token in step 4 is the same as step 1.

Comment: zx81 I'm using Python. leppie I would have to use too many thing to check if the input is right. Barmar I fixed it, also if you could explain how to make this back-reference thing.

Comment: YOu're using `[...]` when you should be using `(...)`. Square brackets are for character classes, not grouping alternatives.

Comment: Regular expressions are [finite-state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), which can't cope with grammars that allow nesting (such as a loop within a loop) since they lack a stack.  Generally, regexes are useful for [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) but not [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).

Comment: @Wyzard Hmm, nice to know, what do you suggest instead of regex?

Comment: [The Python wiki's LanguageParsing page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing) looks like a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
^for ([a-zA-z]\w*) \| if \1 (?:<|>|==|>=|<=) \d+ \| (?:increment|decrement) \1{\n(?: {4}|\t]=).*;\n};$
```

I changed all your `[...]` groups to `(?:...)`, which is a non-capturing group.

I used a back-reference after `for` and `increment|decrement` to require that the variable be the same as after `for`.

Comment: It's generally best to use a raw string when writing a regexp in Python. Otherwise you need to double the backslashes.